# Changing CSS of a tab in jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery UI to do some tabs but I wan't one of the tab to be to the right so I figured I'll use jQuery to change the CSS to float:right but that doesn't help.

Do anyone know a better solution or how I can edit the CSS of one tab?

Comment: Could you show some code? Modifying one of the demos on jQueryUI's site, I was able to make a tab float right simply by adding an inline `style="float:right"` which should be the same thing that `.css()` gives you.

Comment: Here's a working example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/FxXnB/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `float:right` worked for me. Are you adding it to the right element?

```
$("ul.ui-tabs-nav li.ui-state-default:last").css("float", "right");
```

Comment: Thanks, probably dident do that but the code you provided worked, thanks again.